# I want an auto update section for my site

Tags: html, css

I want to have an update section on my site, but it is very annoying to go to every page an change the section. Is there anyway I can have a link or something to a filein my updates section, and then update just that file, so every page is automatically updated?

Comment: Use PHP for dynamic content. Use the `include` function..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something more than HTML and CSS. Personally I would recommend PHP, a server-side scripting languages, which will help you put HTML files together based on pieces, like a header, content, and footer. It's fairly simple, you can use the PHP function include() to get started: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Thanks. I knew I would need more than just HTML and CSS. I considered PHP, I'm just not very skilled, so I tried to avoid it.

Comment: It's not terribly hard, and most of the time you're just putting HTML in a PHP file, with small amounts of PHP here and there <?php yourphpcodehere ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php include to to have that file inserted into a certain area on any page, then changing that file will mean that that change will be reflected on any page which you have included it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Master Page concept if go for ASP.Net
2. In HTML you can add includes where ever you want as a part of common page for all .

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 Solution**
*Warning: May not work on older browsers, not officially supported yet*

---

You can use [`<object>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/object.html) which should look like this:

```
<object name="foo" type="text/html" data="foo.inc"></object>
```

Remember that it is not a self closing tag so you must use `</object>` for it to be valid HTML5.

[`<embed>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/embed.html) can also be used for including external html content (and any MIME type):

```
<embed type="text/html" src="foo.inc">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Javascript? You can load the content using one of [jQuery's AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#mysection").load("ajax/test.html");
```

Remember that it must load a file from the same domain to prevent issues with the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Another approach which I personally wouldn't recommend is putting your section within an [iFrame](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe).